# Microservices and service granularity

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I have never worked with microservices architecture before and there is something important that it is still not clear in what I am reading.

In a microservice architecture a service is a single endpoint or a single module with several endpoints?

Are the endpoints that are fine grained or the granularity is at a higher level? I thought at the beginning that the endpoints were fine grained and this is why there was the risk of making the API too chatty.

I am now finding articles that say that in microservices architecture a service is associated to "bounded context". It seems to me that a bounded context needs more than a single endpoint in an API.

Comment: Have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPvef9R3k-M

Comment: TBH I am not particularly fussed by the naming: micro, macro, huge, small, soa, balboa... whatever :) --- as long as you have sensible deployment options ito of packaging you should be good to go.  An endpoint per BC is fine.  If you want to create finer endpoints then it too is fine.  Behind it all your domain is still going to be built around BCs. A rest-api, for instance, is an integration layer and clients are going to interact with that. It may be easier to expose by process, or BC, or AR or function. Whatever is going to be sensible from a deployment and client point of view should be ok

Comment: @EbenRoux - I still think that it is important to understand the architectural pattern called microservices. In your answer, you are putting together SOA and microservices that are different things. I am trying to understand better their differences.

Comment: microservices and SOA are merely concepts and quite broad at that.  If your goal is to expose your business functionality via some integration layer such as a rest-api then is falls within the realm of "service-oriented".  Decoupling and independent versioning (maintenance) is ideally what we are after.  As with SOA, you are going to find it hard to nail down a decent definition for microservices.  THere are many technologies and techniques that aid in delivery a SOA as there are going to be for microservices :)  I guess we're back to "it depends"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how granular you want your architecture to be. Theoretically, for maximum granularity and according to Single Responsibility Principle you should make a microservice for each Aggregate, in each bounded context. This means that every command should have an endpoint (I assume that each endpoint is reached at a single URI, i.e. `https://server/place/order`).

**If you use a CQRS architecture** then for the read/query side, you could also have a microservice for each read model; in this way you can scale independently each read model (using DB replication or entire microservice instance replication).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking the following two books - [Building Microservices](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033158.do)
  and [Production-Ready Microservices](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920053675.do). Great read for everyone who wants to start journey with microservices.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Both links are useful. They are not an answer to my question though :)

Answer (score 1):

> In a microservice architecture a service is a single endpoint or a single module with several endpoints?

Conceptually, microservices are just services, which is to say they are just objects processing messages.  Messages come in, the service decides whether or not to update its own in memory black box, messages go out.

The integration layer that you put in front of a microservice might have several different "endpoints" to help you pass in new messages to be processed.

> Are the endpoints that are fine grained or the granularity is at a higher level?

Either way - there is fundamentally nothing wrong with having a single endpoint that sends a burst of messages to the service.

> I am now finding articles that say that in microservices architecture a service is associated to "bounded context".

Yes, me too.  I haven't seen any that demonstrate that they mean "Bounded Context" in the sense that Eric Evans originally described in the blue book.

Comment: I read the short book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920046295.do where it says that microservices architectures don't have a middleware (integration level). They do not exchange messages either. There could be an API level though.

Answer (score 0):

Microservices Architecture (MSA), what does this mean? Well, first it means we are talking about architecture rather implementation, second, it means we are talking about something which is in micro level. In service orientation, a software service is a micro size if it is very narrowly functionalized. That means service with only one responsibility, or in another word, service will be small enough (businesswise) to receive a request and response with no server side state management. More gently our micro-service needs to be bounded context. Let me make it clear with a simple example, consider developing a payment service, traditionally this service will provide credit payment, debt payment, pay-pal, web-money and etc. while in MSA each of which will be an independent service.
You can read more in my code-project articles:

[Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-I](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264113/Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-I)

[Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-II](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1268122/Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-II)

[Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-III](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1270792/Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-III)